# .env files not getting loaded when running node server with nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Folder structure

- src
- - server
- - - server.js
- - - .env

I am running a node server with nodemon using the below launch.json, but the environment variables are not being loaded.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server/server.js",
            "restart": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server/.env",
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:

Used "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server/.env",
Instead of: "runtimeArgs": [
"--require=dotenv/config"
]
Now all the env variables are loaded!

Comment: How have you configured dotenv?

Comment: :) I haven't. I am checking the documentation now. I see that if loaded in the server.js file you can do `require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../.env') });` but I'm not sure how to configure it in the launch.json

Answer (score 0):

Used: `"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server/.env",`

Instead of: `"runtimeArgs": [ "--require=dotenv/config" ]`

Now all the env variables are loaded!